# How to convert string to date in talend

Tags: talend

I want to convert string

> 1516270217

to date format

> hh:mm dd-MM-YY

Comment: What format is the input in? Unix/Windows timestamp in decimal? If it's in the `hhmmddMMYY` format, just add separators...

Comment: I want to convert the string "1516270217" to date format as mentioned above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: When you ask a question, you should include: 1) Any findings from when you tried to solve the problem yourself, including research and attempts. 2) A question about real code, not a question about how to implement something or where to start. 3) A very brief background of what you're trying to ultimately accomplish with this, to avoid an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in a tmap for example.

```
TalendDate.formatDate("hh:mm dd-MM-YY",TalendDate.parseDate("HHmmddMMyy",row21.newColumn))
```